# error while running "grunt serve:dist"

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, gruntjs

I created the mean stack seed using https://github.com/angular-fullstack/generator-angular-fullstack

But when i try to do "grunt serve:dist" i am getting this error

```
Running "ngAnnotate:dist" (ngAnnotate) task
>> 2 files successfully generated.

Running "copy:dist" (copy) task
Created 134 directories, copied 710 files

jit-grunt: Plugin for the "babel" task not found.
If you have installed the plugin already, please setting the static mapping.
See https://github.com/shootaroo/jit-grunt#static-mappings

Warning: Task "babel:server" failed. Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
```

Here is my package.json. Please advise me what am i doing wrong.

```
{
  "name": "invoice1",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "main": "server/app.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "aws-sdk": "^2.2.42",
    "babel-runtime": "^5.8.20",
    "bluebird": "^2.9.34",
    "body-parser": "^1.13.3",
    "composable-middleware": "^0.3.0",
    "compression": "^1.5.2",
    "connect-mongo": "^0.8.1",
    "connect-multiparty": "^2.0.0",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.3.5",
    "crypto": "0.0.3",
    "ejs": "^2.3.3",
    "errorhandler": "^1.4.2",
    "express": "^4.13.3",
    "express-jwt": "^3.0.0",
    "express-session": "^1.11.3",
    "grunt-build-control": "^0.6.3",
    "install": "^0.5.4",
    "jit-grunt": "^0.9.1",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^5.0.0",
    "lodash": "^3.10.1",
    "lusca": "^1.3.0",
    "method-override": "^2.3.5",
    "mongoose": "^4.1.2",
    "mongoose-timestamp": "^0.5.0",
    "morgan": "~1.6.1",
    "node-mailjet": "^1.1.0",
    "npm": "^3.7.5",
    "passport": "~0.3.0",
    "passport-google-oauth": "~0.2.0",
    "passport-local": "^1.0.0",
    "serve-favicon": "^2.3.0",
    "wait-until": "0.0.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^6.0.0",
    "babel-core": "^5.6.4",
    "grunt": "~0.4.5",
    "grunt-wiredep": "^2.0.0",
    "grunt-concurrent": "^2.0.1",
    "grunt-contrib-clean": "~0.7.0",
    "grunt-contrib-concat": "^0.5.1",
    "grunt-contrib-copy": "^0.8.0",
    "grunt-contrib-cssmin": "~0.14.0",
    "grunt-contrib-imagemin": "~1.0.0",
    "grunt-contrib-jshint": "~0.11.2",
    "grunt-contrib-uglify": "~0.11.0",
    "grunt-contrib-watch": "~0.6.1",
    "grunt-ts": "~5.2.0",
    "grunt-tsd": "~0.1.0",
    "grunt-tslint": "~3.0.1",
    "grunt-google-cdn": "~0.4.0",
    "grunt-jscs": "^2.1.0",
    "grunt-newer": "^1.1.1",
    "grunt-ng-annotate": "^1.0.1",
    "grunt-ng-constant": "^1.1.0",
    "grunt-filerev": "^2.3.1",
    "grunt-usemin": "^3.0.0",
    "grunt-env": "~0.4.1",
    "grunt-node-inspector": "^0.4.1",
    "grunt-nodemon": "^0.4.0",
    "grunt-angular-templates": "^0.5.4",
    "grunt-dom-munger": "^3.4.0",
    "grunt-protractor-runner": "^2.0.0",
    "grunt-injector": "^0.6.0",
    "grunt-karma": "~0.12.0",
    "grunt-build-control": "^0.6.0",
    "jit-grunt": "^0.9.1",
    "grunt-express-server": "^0.5.1",
    "grunt-postcss": "~0.7.1",
    "grunt-open": "~0.2.3",
    "time-grunt": "^1.2.1",
    "grunt-mocha-test": "~0.12.7",
    "grunt-mocha-istanbul": "^3.0.1",
    "open": "~0.0.4",
    "jshint-stylish": "~2.1.0",
    "connect-livereload": "^0.5.3",
    "istanbul": "~0.4.1",
    "chai": "^3.2.0",
    "sinon": "^1.16.1",
    "chai-as-promised": "^5.1.0",
    "chai-things": "^0.2.0",
    "karma": "~0.13.3",
    "karma-ng-scenario": "~0.1.0",
    "karma-firefox-launcher": "~0.1.6",
    "karma-script-launcher": "~0.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~0.2.0",
    "karma-requirejs": "~0.2.2",
    "karma-jade-preprocessor": "0.0.11",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "~0.2.0",
    "karma-ng-html2js-preprocessor": "~0.2.0",
    "karma-spec-reporter": "~0.0.20",
    "sinon-chai": "^2.8.0",
    "mocha": "^2.2.5",
    "karma-mocha": "^0.2.0",
    "karma-chai-plugins": "^0.6.0",
    "requirejs": "~2.1.11",
    "phantomjs": "^1.9.18",
    "proxyquire": "^1.0.1",
    "supertest": "^1.1.0"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "^4.2.3",
    "npm": "^2.14.7"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server",
    "test": "grunt test",
    "update-webdriver": "node node_modules/grunt-protractor-runner/node_modules/protractor/bin/webdriver-manager update"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

--------EDIT-------

Below is my Gruntfile.js

```
// Generated on 2016-02-24 using generator-angular-fullstack 3.3.0
'use strict';

module.exports = function (grunt) {
  var localConfig;
  try {
    localConfig = require('./server/config/local.env');
  } catch(e) {
    localConfig = {};
  }

  // Load grunt tasks automatically, when needed
  require('jit-grunt')(grunt, {
    express: 'grunt-express-server',
    useminPrepare: 'grunt-usemin',
    ngtemplates: 'grunt-angular-templates',
    cdnify: 'grunt-google-cdn',
    protractor: 'grunt-protractor-runner',
    buildcontrol: 'grunt-build-control',
    istanbul_check_coverage: 'grunt-mocha-istanbul',
    ngconstant: 'grunt-ng-constant'
  });

  // Time how long tasks take. Can help when optimizing build times
  require('time-grunt')(grunt);

  // Define the configuration for all the tasks
  grunt.initConfig({

    // Project settings
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
    yeoman: {
      // configurable paths
      client: require('./bower.json').appPath || 'client',
      server: 'server',
      dist: 'dist'
    },
    express: {
      options: {
        port: process.env.PORT || 9000
      },
      dev: {
        options: {
          script: '<%= yeoman.server %>',
          debug: true
        }
      },
      prod: {
        options: {
          script: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/<%= yeoman.server %>'
        }
      }
    },
    open: {
      server: {
        url: 'http://localhost:<%= express.options.port %>'
      }
    },
    watch: {
      ts: {
        files: ['<%= yeoman.client %>/{app,components}/**/!(*.spec|*.mock).ts'],
        tasks: ['ts:client']
      },
      ngconstant: {
        files: ['<%= yeoman.server %>/config/environment/shared.js'],
        tasks: ['ngconstant']
      },
      injectJS: {
        files: [
          '<%= yeoman.client %>/{app,components}/**/!(*.spec|*.mock).ts',
          '!<%= yeoman.client %>/app/app.js'
        ],
        tasks: ['injector:scripts']
      },
      injectCss: {
        files: ['<%= yeoman.client %>/{app,components}/**/*.css'],
        tasks: ['injector:css']
      },
      mochaTest: {
        files: ['<%= yeoman.server %>/**/*.{spec,integration}.ts'],
        tasks: ['env:test', 'mochaTest']
      },
      jsTest: {
        files: ['<%= yeoman.client %>/{app,components}/**/*.{spec,mock}.ts'],
        tasks: ['newer:tslint:all', 'newer:ts:client_test',, 'wiredep:test', 'karma']
      },
      gruntfile: {
        files: ['Gruntfile.js']
      },
      livereload: {
        files: [
          '{.tmp,<%= yeoman.client %>}/{app,components}/**/*.{css,html}',
          '{.tmp,<%= yeoman.client %>}/{app,components}/**/!(*.spec|*.mock).ts',
          '<%= yeoman.client %>/assets/images/{,*//*}*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif,webp,svg}'
        ],
        options: {
          livereload: true
        }
      },
      express: {
        files: ['<%= yeoman.server %>/**/*.{js,json}'],
        tasks: ['express:dev', 'wait'],
        options: {
          livereload: true,
          spawn: false //Without this option specified express won't be reloaded
        }
      },
      bower: {
        files: ['bower.json'],
        tasks: ['wiredep']
      },
    },

    // Make sure code styles are up to par and there are no obvious mistakes
    jshint: {
      options: {
        jshintrc: '<%= yeoman.client %>/.jshintrc',
        reporter: require('jshint-stylish')
      },
      server: {
        options: {
          jshintrc: '<%= yeoman.server %>/.jshintrc'
        },
        src: ['<%= yeoman.server %>/**/!(*.spec|*.integration).js']
      },
      serverTest: {
        options: {
          jshintrc: '<%= yeoman.server %>/.jshintrc-spec'
        },
        src: ['<%= yeoman.server %>/**/*.{spec,integration}.js']
      },
      all: ['<%= yeoman.client %>/{app,components}/**/!(*.spec|*.mock|app.constant).js'],
      test: {
        src: ['<%= yeoman.client %>/{app,components}/**/*.{spec,mock}.js']
      }
    },

    tslint: {
      options: {
        configuration: '<%= yeoman.client %>/tslint.json'
      },
      all: {
        src: ['<%= yeoman.client %>/{app,components}/**/!(*.spec|*.mock).ts']
      }
    },

    jscs: {
      options: {
        config: ".jscsrc"
      },
      main: {
        files: {
          src: [
            '<%= yeoman.client %>/app/**/*.js',
            '<%= yeoman.server %>/**/*.js'
          ]
        }
      }
    },

    // Empties folders to start fresh
    clean: {
      dist: {
        files: [{
          dot: true,
          src: [
            '.tmp',
            '<%= yeoman.dist %>/!(.git*|.openshift|Procfile)**'
          ]
        }]
      },
      server: '.tmp'
    },

    // Add vendor prefixed styles
    postcss: {
      options: {
        map: true,
        processors: [
          require('autoprefixer')({browsers: ['last 2 version']})
        ]
      },
      dist: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: '.tmp/',
          src: '{,*/}*.css',
          dest: '.tmp/'
        }]
      }
    },

    // Debugging with node inspector
    'node-inspector': {
      custom: {
        options: {
          'web-host': 'localhost'
        }
      }
    },

    // Use nodemon to run server in debug mode with an initial breakpoint
    nodemon: {
      debug: {
        script: '<%= yeoman.server %>',
        options: {
          nodeArgs: ['--debug-brk'],
          env: {
            PORT: process.env.PORT || 9000
          },
          callback: function (nodemon) {
            nodemon.on('log', function (event) {
              console.log(event.colour);
            });

            // opens browser on initial server start
            nodemon.on('config:update', function () {
              setTimeout(function () {
                require('open')('http://localhost:8080/debug?port=5858');
              }, 500);
            });
          }
        }
      }
    },

    // Automatically inject Bower components into the app and karma.conf.js
    wiredep: {
      options: {
        exclude: [
          /bootstrap.js/,
          '/json3/',
          '/es5-shim/'
        ]
      },
      client: {
        src: '<%= yeoman.client %>/index.html',
        ignorePath: '<%= yeoman.client %>/',
      },
      test: {
        src: './karma.conf.js',
        devDependencies: true
      }
    },

    // Renames files for browser caching purposes
    filerev: {
      dist: {
        src: [
          '<%= yeoman.dist %>/<%= yeoman.client %>/!(bower_components){,*/}*.{js,css}',
          '<%= yeoman.dist %>/<%= yeoman.client %>/assets/images/{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif,webp,svg}',
          '<%= yeoman.dist %>/<%= yeoman.client %>/assets/fonts/*'
        ]
      }
    },

    // Reads HTML for usemin blocks to enable smart builds that automatically
    // concat, minify and revision files. Creates configurations in memory so
    // additional tasks can operate on them
    useminPrepare: {
      html: ['<%= yeoman.client %>/index.html'],
      options: {
        dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/<%= yeoman.client %>'
      }
    },

    // Performs rewrites based on rev and the useminPrepare configuration
    usemin: {
      html: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/<%= yeoman.client %>/{,!(bower_components)/**/}*.html'],
      css: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/<%= yeoman.client %>/!(bower_components){,*/}*.css'],
      js: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/<%= yeoman.client %>/!(bower_components){,*/}*.js'],
      options: {
        assetsDirs: [
          '<%= yeoman.dist %>/<%= yeoman.client %>',
          '<%= yeoman.dist %>/<%= yeoman.client %>/assets/images'
        ],
        // This is so we update image references in our ng-templates
        patterns: {
          js: [
            [/(assets\/images\/.*?\.(?:gif|jpeg|jpg|png|webp|svg))/gm, 'Update the JS to reference our revved images']
          ]
        }
      }
    },

    // The following *-min tasks produce minified files in the dist folder
    imagemin: {
      dist: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: '<%= yeoman.client %>/assets/images',
          src: '{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif,svg}',
          dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/<%= yeoman.client %>/assets/images'
        }]
      }
    },

    // Allow the use of non-minsafe AngularJS files. Automatically makes it
    // minsafe compatible so Uglify does not destroy the ng references
    ngAnnotate: {
      dist: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: '.tmp/concat',
          src: '**/*.js',
          dest: '.tmp/concat'
        }]
      }
    },

    // Dynamically generate angular constant `appConfig` from
    // `server/config/environment/shared.js`
    ngconstant: {
      options: {
        name: 'invoice1App.constants',
        dest: '<%= yeoman.client %>/app/app.constant.js',
        deps: [],
        wrap: true,
        configPath: '<%= yeoman.server %>/config/environment/shared'
      },
      app: {
        constants: function() {
          return {
            appConfig: require('./' + grunt.config.get('ngconstant.options.configPath'))
          };
        }
      }
    },

    // Package all the html partials into a single javascript payload
    ngtemplates: {
      options: {
        // This should be the name of your apps angular module
        module: 'invoice1App',
        htmlmin: {
          collapseBooleanAttributes: true,
          collapseWhitespace: true,
          removeAttributeQuotes: true,
          removeEmptyAttributes: true,
          removeRedundantAttributes: true,
          removeScriptTypeAttributes: true,
          removeStyleLinkTypeAttributes: true
        },
        usemin: 'app/app.js'
      },
      main: {
        cwd: '<%= yeoman.client %>',
        src: ['{app,components}/**/*.html'],
        dest: '.tmp/templates.js'
      },
      tmp: {
        cwd: '.tmp',
        src: ['{app,components}/**/*.html'],
        dest: '.tmp/tmp-templates.js'
      }
    },

    // Replace Google CDN references
    cdnify: {
      dist: {
        html: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/<%= yeoman.client %>/*.html']
      }
    },

    // Copies remaining files to places other tasks can use
    copy: {
      dist: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          dot: true,
          cwd: '<%= yeoman.client %>',
          dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/<%= yeoman.client %>',
          src: [
            '*.{ico,png,txt}',
            '.htaccess',
            'bower_components/**/*',
            'assets/images/{,*/}*.{webp}',
            'assets/fonts/**/*',
            'index.html'
          ]
        }, {
          expand: true,
          cwd: '.tmp/images',
          dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/<%= yeoman.client %>/assets/images',
          src: ['generated/*']
        }, {
          expand: true,
          dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>',
          src: [
            'package.json',
            '<%= yeoman.server %>/**/*',
            '!<%= yeoman.server %>/config/local.env.sample.js'
          ]
        }]
      },
      styles: {
        expand: true,
        cwd: '<%= yeoman.client %>',
        dest: '.tmp/',
        src: ['{app,components}/**/*.css']
      },
      constant: {
        expand: true,
        cwd: '<%= yeoman.client %>',
        dest: '.tmp/',
        src: ['app/app.constant.js']
      }
    },

    buildcontrol: {
      options: {
        dir: '<%= yeoman.dist %>',
        commit: true,
        push: true,
        connectCommits: false,
        message: 'Built %sourceName% from commit %sourceCommit% on branch %sourceBranch%'
      },
      heroku: {
        options: {
          remote: 'heroku',
          branch: 'master'
        }
      },
      openshift: {
        options: {
          remote: 'openshift',
          branch: 'master'
        }
      }
    },

    // Run some tasks in parallel to speed up the build process
    concurrent: {
      pre: [
        'ngconstant',
        'copy:constant'
      ],
      server: [
        'ts:client',
        'copy:constant',
      ],
      test: [
        'ts:client',
        'copy:constant',
        'ts:client_test',
      ],
      debug: {
        tasks: [
          'nodemon',
          'node-inspector'
        ],
        options: {
          logConcurrentOutput: true
        }
      },
      dist: [
        'ts:client',
        'copy:constant',
        'imagemin'
      ]
    },

    // Test settings
    karma: {
      unit: {
        configFile: 'karma.conf.js',
        singleRun: true
      }
    },

    mochaTest: {
      options: {
        reporter: 'spec',
        require: 'mocha.conf.js',
        timeout: 5000 // set default mocha spec timeout
      },
      unit: {
        src: ['<%= yeoman.server %>/**/*.spec.js']
      },
      integration: {
        src: ['<%= yeoman.server %>/**/*.integration.js']
      }
    },

    mocha_istanbul: {
      unit: {
        options: {
          excludes: ['**/*.{spec,mock,integration}.js'],
          reporter: 'spec',
          require: ['mocha.conf.js'],
          mask: '**/*.spec.js',
          coverageFolder: 'coverage/server/unit'
        },
        src: '<%= yeoman.server %>'
      },
      integration: {
        options: {
          excludes: ['**/*.{spec,mock,integration}.js'],
          reporter: 'spec',
          require: ['mocha.conf.js'],
          mask: '**/*.integration.js',
          coverageFolder: 'coverage/server/integration'
        },
        src: '<%= yeoman.server %>'
      }
    },

    istanbul_check_coverage: {
      default: {
        options: {
          coverageFolder: 'coverage/**',
          check: {
            lines: 80,
            statements: 80,
            branches: 80,
            functions: 80
          }
        }
      }
    },

    protractor: {
      options: {
        configFile: 'protractor.conf.js'
      },
      chrome: {
        options: {
          args: {
            browser: 'chrome'
          }
        }
      }
    },

    env: {
      test: {
        NODE_ENV: 'test'
      },
      prod: {
        NODE_ENV: 'production'
      },
      all: localConfig
    },

    // Compiles ES6 to JavaScript using Babel
    babel: {
      options: {
        sourceMap: true,
        optional: [
          'es7.classProperties'
        ]
      },
      server: {
        options: {
          optional: ['runtime']
        },
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: '<%= yeoman.server %>',
          src: ['**/*.js'],
          dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/<%= yeoman.server %>'
        }]
      }
    },

    ts: {
      options: {
        sourceMap: true,
        failOnTypeErrors: false
      },
      client: {
        tsconfig: './tsconfig.client.json',
        outDir: '.tmp'
      },
      client_test: {
        tsconfig: './tsconfig.client.test.json',
        outDir: '.tmp/test'
      }
    },

    tsd: {
      install: {
        options: {
          command: 'reinstall',
          config: './tsd.json'
        }
      },
      install_test: {
        options: {
          command: 'reinstall',
          config: './tsd_test.json'
        }
      }
    },

    injector: {
      options: {},
      // Inject application script files into index.html (doesn't include bower)
      scripts: {
        options: {
          transform: function(filePath) {
            var yoClient = grunt.config.get('yeoman.client');
            filePath = filePath.replace('/' + yoClient + '/', '');
            filePath = filePath.replace('/.tmp/', '');
            filePath = filePath.replace('.ts', '.js');
            return '<script src="' + filePath + '"></script>';
          },
          sort: function(a, b) {
            var module = /\.module\.ts$/;
            var aMod = module.test(a);
            var bMod = module.test(b);
            // inject *.module.js first
            return (aMod === bMod) ? 0 : (aMod ? -1 : 1);
          },
          starttag: '<!-- injector:js -->',
          endtag: '<!-- endinjector -->'
        },
        files: {
          '<%= yeoman.client %>/index.html': [
               [
                 '<%= yeoman.client %>/{app,components}/**/!(*.spec|*.mock).ts',
                 '<%= yeoman.client %>/app/app.constant.js',
                 '!{.tmp,<%= yeoman.client %>}/app/app.{js,ts}'
               ]
            ]
        }
      },

      // Inject component css into index.html
      css: {
        options: {
          transform: function(filePath) {
            var yoClient = grunt.config.get('yeoman.client');
            filePath = filePath.replace('/' + yoClient + '/', '');
            filePath = filePath.replace('/.tmp/', '');
            return '<link rel="stylesheet" href="' + filePath + '">';
          },
          starttag: '<!-- injector:css -->',
          endtag: '<!-- endinjector -->'
        },
        files: {
          '<%= yeoman.client %>/index.html': [
            '<%= yeoman.client %>/{app,components}/**/*.css'
          ]
        }
      }
    },
  });

  // Used for delaying livereload until after server has restarted
  grunt.registerTask('wait', function () {
    grunt.log.ok('Waiting for server reload...');

    var done = this.async();

    setTimeout(function () {
      grunt.log.writeln('Done waiting!');
      done();
    }, 1500);
  });

  grunt.registerTask('express-keepalive', 'Keep grunt running', function() {
    this.async();
  });

  grunt.registerTask('serve', function (target) {
    if (target === 'dist') {
      return grunt.task.run(['build', 'env:all', 'env:prod', 'express:prod', 'wait', 'open', 'express-keepalive']);
    }

    if (target === 'debug') {
      return grunt.task.run([
        'clean:server',
        'env:all',
        'concurrent:pre',
        'tsd',
        'concurrent:server',
        'injector',
        'wiredep:client',
        'postcss',
        'concurrent:debug'
      ]);
    }

    grunt.task.run([
      'clean:server',
      'env:all',
      'concurrent:pre',
      'tsd',
      'concurrent:server',
      'injector',
      'wiredep:client',
      'postcss',
      'express:dev',
      'wait',
      'open',
      'watch'
    ]);
  });

  grunt.registerTask('server', function () {
    grunt.log.warn('The `server` task has been deprecated. Use `grunt serve` to start a server.');
    grunt.task.run(['serve']);
  });

  grunt.registerTask('test', function(target, option) {
    if (target === 'server') {
      return grunt.task.run([
        'env:all',
        'env:test',
        'mochaTest:unit',
        'mochaTest:integration'
      ]);
    }

    else if (target === 'client') {
      return grunt.task.run([
        'clean:server',
        'env:all',
        'concurrent:pre',
        'ts:client',
        'ts:client_test',
        'tsd',
        'concurrent:test',
        'injector',
        'postcss',
        'wiredep:test',
        'karma'
      ]);
    }

    else if (target === 'e2e') {

      if (option === 'prod') {
        return grunt.task.run([
          'build',
          'env:all',
          'env:prod',
          'express:prod',
          'protractor'
        ]);
      }

      else {
        return grunt.task.run([
          'clean:server',
          'env:all',
          'env:test',
          'concurrent:pre',
          'tsd:install',
          'tsd:install_test',
          'ts:client',
          'ts:client_test',
          'concurrent:test',
          'injector',
          'wiredep:client',
          'postcss',
          'express:dev',
          'protractor'
        ]);
      }
    }

    else if (target === 'coverage') {

      if (option === 'unit') {
        return grunt.task.run([
          'env:all',
          'env:test',
          'mocha_istanbul:unit'
        ]);
      }

      else if (option === 'integration') {
        return grunt.task.run([
          'env:all',
          'env:test',
          'mocha_istanbul:integration'
        ]);
      }

      else if (option === 'check') {
        return grunt.task.run([
          'istanbul_check_coverage'
        ]);
      }

      else {
        return grunt.task.run([
          'env:all',
          'env:test',
          'mocha_istanbul',
          'istanbul_check_coverage'
        ]);
      }

    }

    else grunt.task.run([
      'test:server',
      'test:client'
    ]);
  });

  grunt.registerTask('build', [
    'clean:dist',
    'concurrent:pre',
    'tsd',
    'concurrent:dist',
    'injector',
    'wiredep:client',
    'useminPrepare',
    'postcss',
    'ngtemplates',
    'concat',
    'ngAnnotate',
    'copy:dist',
    'babel:server',
    'cdnify',
    'cssmin',
    'uglify',
    'filerev',
    'usemin'
  ]);

  grunt.registerTask('default', [
    'newer:tslint',
    'test',
    'build'
  ]);
};
```

Comment: Please post your .babelrc file and/or babel:server task from Gruntfile.js

Answer (score 0):

This would be easy to look at if you supplied your gruntfile or .babelrc, but here goes... You don't have any babel plugins or presets in your package.json, but I assume that your config says something like

```
{
  "presets": ["es2015"],
  "plugins": ["transform-class-properties"]
}
```

and you need to install these packages.

`npm install --save-dev babel-preset-es2015 babel-plugin-transform-class-properties`

Comment: thansk for your answer but this doesn't seem to be the issue. I don't have any .babelrc in my setup. Also i do not see the presets/plugins definition u mentioned. I edited my question and provided the Gruntfile.js. Can you please take a look?

Comment: any thoughts on this?

Comment: It doesn't make much sense to me. The gruntfile is all over the place, and the task in question, `babel:server`, isn't even defined or listed in grunt:build. Are you really sure this is the gruntfile being used?

Comment: My apologies, i uploaded the wrong grunt file. I have updated the question with the right one. Kindly take a look and see if i am missing anything

Comment: Install grunt-babel and babel-preset-es2015: `npm install --save-dev grunt-babel babel-preset-es2015` and try running grunt serve:dist again. It should run a bit further than before.

Comment: Thanks @dannyjolie. Tried that, now getting this error,         

Running "babel:server" (babel) task
Warning: [BABEL] server/api/common/constants.js: Using removed Babel 5 option: base.optional - Put the specific transforms you want in the `plugins` option Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.

Comment: apologies for not getting back on this, i am stuck with the error mentioned in the previous comment. I tried running with --force option and then i get this error "import express from 'express';
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected reserved word"